# Define Hex Constant (68000)?

Tags: assembly, 68000

How do I define a hex constant in 68000 assembly? I need to compute the logic expression X'Y + X'Z + YZ, where X, Y, and Z are hex constants, and the result is displayed in binary. I wrote the code to compute the expression, I'm just not sure how to define the constants in hex..and then display them in binary.

For reference, X is 000F, Y is 0033, and Z is 0055.

X:        DC        ???

Comment: Depends on the assembler, but *most* assemblers for the 68K prefixed hex constants with a dollar sign, as in: `X : DC $1234abcd`

Comment: And most assemblers want a *size specification* with the `dc`- So its rather like `X: DC.L $1234abcd

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which assembler you're using. With gas syntax, for example, you would just write `0xF`, `0x33` and `0x55`, so something like

```
.int 0xF*0x33+0xF*0x55+0x33*0x55
```